# Saving State of the checkbox in a custom list view with Checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have a list view with checkboxes and I want that when user selects any check box and closes the application, and again opens the application, the same checkboxes should be selected. i.e I have to save the state of the checkboxes of the listview items using the sharedpref method.
Here I have implemented the same, but not getting the desired result, I have tried a lot please help me.

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Editor editor;
    Context context;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.cB = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_category);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());

        holder.cB.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue", false));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(holder.cB.isChecked()){

            editor.putBoolean("CheckValue", holder.cB.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        CheckBox cB;
    }

}
```

CutomListviewActivity.java

```
public class CustomListViewActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
                String s=fullObject.getName().toString();
                Toast.makeText(CustomListViewActivity.this, "You have chosen: " + " " + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(CustomListViewActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }  
        });


    }



    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults()
    {
        ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

        SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("John Smith");

        results.add(sr1);

        sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("Jane Doe");

        results.add(sr1);

        sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("Steve Young");

        results.add(sr1);

        sr1 = new SearchResults();
        sr1.setName("Fred Jones");

        results.add(sr1);



        return results;
    }
}
```

GetterSetter Class

```
package com.list;

public class SearchResults {
     private String name = "";


     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }


    }
```

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/name"
  android:textSize="14sp" 
  android:textStyle="bold" 
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="TextView"/>


  <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/cb_category"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Custom ListView Contents" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can store some data about checked checkboxes in DB or sharedPreferences. And set status inside method getView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost right. Just need to do some changes...

Check My code of `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for checkbox.. I hope it will work

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Editor editor;
    Context context;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.cB = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_category);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());

        holder.cB.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
       holder.cB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+position, isChecked);
       editor.commit();
       }});
        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        CheckBox cB;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering. I understand ur approach bro but actually there comes an exception named null pointer on sharedpreference sharedprefs=context.getsharedpref...... line.. please check and revert me back..

Comment: writte this line in your constructor this.context=context

Comment: ok Thanks. me checking now and if it is done i will let u know

Comment: Hello Cap, How will the program got to know which checkbox is selected?

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but when I hit back button and then come back the wrong check boxes stay checked

Comment: @NiranjPatel is it good practice to save in shared preferences? Or is there any other alternative?

Comment: @GopsAB you can also use local array

Comment: You can't get a guarantee  of how many time the get view will be called, so you need to avoid creating objects there as much as you can, i have edited the answer and putted Shared Preference as global variable, and the init of sharedPreference in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean array to record the checked state (in the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`) for each position item, then call `setChecked()` after `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. Just that simple.