# How to effectively store checkbox values in Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, sharedpreferences

For the past two weeks, I have been struggling to produce a solution to store my checkbox values next to each of my listview items when I exit and open the app. Essentially, I have a custom BaseAdapter class which populates the listview with installed applications on the users phone and a checkbox next to each installed app. When I scroll down the checkbox states stay;however, when I click back or exit and come back it doesn't stay.

[image]

I used SharedPreferences in almost every way possible. My last way was using a for loop to create a SharedPreference for each one and restore the boolean in the for loop as well and to store a boolean true and false (for checked and unchecked respectively) in if and else statements.

Here is my code for my BaseAdapter class using SharedPreferences:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

//

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/LGRicg4U , http://pastebin.com/c4WfmhMK , http://pastebin.com/gFuuM4dY, http://pastebin.com/4Q7EP9G4
    // http://pastebin.com/Te2g072w,  http://pastebin.com/NLT5iUiA ,

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    String PACKAGE_NAME;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];

    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
        TextView packageName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1= (CheckBox)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);



        // Make sure to define it again!
        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;


        final String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);


        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);


        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        Log.d("just loaded??", PACKAGE_NAME);


        Log.d("just loaded 2?", appName+position);



        // CHANGE UP EVERYTHING! MAKE THIS SHIT WORK, TIGGA!


        for(int i= 0; i<packageList.size(); i++){
            sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(i), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(String.valueOf(i),false));


        }

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(position), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(position), true);
                    Log.d("put true", appName+position);

                    editor.apply();

                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                    Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(position), false);
                    Log.d("put false", appName+position);

                    editor.apply();

                }

            }


        });

        return convertView;

    }




}
```

I have also created a DatabaseHandler class and Object class for using SQLite database to store my checkbox values instead after unsuccessfully storing it with SharedPreferences.

Here are the pastebin links so I don't clog the post:

DatabaseHandler class: http://pastebin.com/NzKhBiZ3

Object class:  http://pastebin.com/Jp3BLXba

I know that there are many posts, blogs, and links on using custom adapters/listviews and saving checkboxes and button states etc using SQLite and SharedPreferences, but I assure you I  have done my fair share of research for weeks, but I haven't been able to find something that works for my specific case.

Some examples:

[Saving State of the checkbox in a custom list view with Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621804/saving-state-of-the-checkbox-in-a-custom-list-view-with-checkboxes?rq=1)

http://blog.csdn.net/qu213/article/details/9289349

*What would be the most optimal option in my particular case and How would I produce a solution in my situation to successfully save the checkbox states next to each installed app listview item that would be saved after I exit the application and re-enter? Some code would really be of help.*

Thank you for your time.

Let me know if you need me to include any xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved your problem. Please try thise code and see if it works.

```
 for(int i= 0; i<packageList.size(); i++){
            PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;

            sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.d("just got sharedpref??", PACKAGE_NAME);


            holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME,false));
            Log.d("just got boolean??", PACKAGE_NAME);


        }

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(packageInfo.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, true);
                    Log.d("put true", packageInfo.packageName);

                    editor.apply();

                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                    Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, false);
                    Log.d("put false", packageInfo.packageName);

                    editor.apply();

                }

            }


        });
```

I passed in the packagenames for the keys. :)

Answer (score 1):

what i would suggest in your case is to define an object that would deal with storing and retrieving state data. Lets say you have an AppHandler class as your main object and AppState class
for keeping state related data such as your checkboxes.

```
public class AppHandler {

    private List<AppState> lastInstalledApp;
    @transient
    private Gson            gson;


    public void retrieve(SharedPreferences pref){

        // parse the gson from shared preferences
        // create the lastInstalledApp list
        String jsonState = pref.getString("APP_STATE", null);
        if(jsonState != null)
           lastInstalledApp = gson.fromJson(jsonState, lastInstalledApp.getClass());
    }

    public void store(SharedPreferences pref){

        // store the data to shared preferences
    }


    public List<AppState> getAppList(){

        return lastInstalledApp;
    }

    public static class AppState{

        protected boolean lastCheckbox;
        protected String name;
        public boolean isLastCheckbox() {
            return lastCheckbox;
        }
        public void setLastCheckbox(boolean lastCheckbox) {
            this.lastCheckbox = lastCheckbox;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


    }
```

Use shared preferences to store the entire AppHandler object as a JSON string (use GSON for this) so you access the storage file only once and not every time you want to access a single checkbox state. You can retrieve and store this data on your activity (the adapter initiate it with your `appHandler.getAppList()` data):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    appHandler = new AppHandler();
    appHandler.retrieve(getSharedPreferences());
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    appHandler.store(getSharedPreferences());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

within the your custom adapter access the specific application by their package names in order to get the state of checkbox. you may even extend `ArrayList` and add some methods like `getAppByName()` so you can keep a clear distinction between objects.
when changing the checkbox state update the equivalent boolean value of the `AppState` object. This is in general terms.

Comment: I read over your answer but I am confused where I would go with the implementation. Would I  use similar code as I did in my adapter in the store method-- creating a SharedPreference, putting the boolean in for the item? And I guess I would use the getBoolean method in retrieve method? Im having trouble understanding what would go in  parse the gson from shared preferences, create the lastInstalledApp list. Would GSON be best approach. Because I may need all the key values of checked boxes. I appreciate your help and apologize for the questions. I guess little more explanation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I think I am kinda understanding a bit more now. But addressing the above would really help xD

Comment: you parse/store JSON only on onCreate() and onDestroy() so you store the last apps installed. with their boolean values. based on app package name you get the last stored boolean value and set it to the corresponding checkbox. if the user installs/uninstalls a new app, you add/remove it to/from the lastInstalledApps list.GSON is very easy to use and effective. if it is the best choice? hard to say. but has worked fine for me so far.

Comment: Thanks!! :) last apps installed? or do you mean currently installed apps? But I see. So I guess I have to learn a bit more about JSON. Got a lot to do haha. Um would I be at a disadvantage using GSON like written in the code above? I know the main differences are that GSON can use the Object definition to directly create an object of the desired type. JSONObject needs to be parsed manually. So like let's say I need the app package name of all checked apps, would I be able to get then with GSON? Or would I need to use JSON?

Comment: i named it last installed because when storing, they will save the last installed applications' states so when your application will run again the list needs to be update with the current applications installed. GSON is a good google's library. you may use pure JSONObject but i prefer GSON for simplicity.and trust me u dont need to learn a lot abt JSON/GSON. quite straightforward

Comment: Okay so there both useable that's good to hear. I know that    JSONObject object; object.getString("key"); <-- would not be possible on gson       Guess I'll have to find an equivalent for GSON

Comment: Also I am trying to download the gson google library but everything has been deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite database ...Everytime the user checks/unchecks the value make an entry in the database.

> App1 checked
>
> App2 checked
>
> App3 checked
>
> App4 unchecked

Comment: Am I on the right track with my two classes? The problem is that if the user downloads any other app it can offset the database

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I know how an SQLite database works, but I was trying to figure out the implementation in case for my particular case.

Comment: @XiJiaopin sorry I dont understand the issue then...u need to just keep a flag for each app..when the user adds a new app the default flag is unchecked

Comment: That's what I am tryna figure out how to write the code for ahha