# Saving checkbox state in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Seems like I'm doing something wrong since whenever I open the fragment, all the checkboxes are checked.

But when I click on one of them for unchecking, I again call the savePreference method, where checkBox.isChecked is false. But inside the method, the value is set to true. Therefore I assume that's why everytime I run the app, the checkboxes are always checked.

EDIT: isChecked will always return me true, even when I uncheck

Here's my code:

```
public class FilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mFilters;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mPictures;
    private Typeface Bebas, DroidSans;
    private CheckBox checkBox;


    public FilterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filters, ArrayList<Integer> pictures) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFilters = filters;
        this.mPictures = pictures;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mFilters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_filter_item, null);
        }

        checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked)
                    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
                else {
                    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
                }

            }
        });

        loadSavedPreferences();

        DroidSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSans.ttf");

        ImageView filter_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_picture);
        TextView filter_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_category);

        filter_category.setTypeface(DroidSans);
        filter_category.setText(mFilters.get(position));
        filter_img.setBackgroundResource(mPictures.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
        if (checkBoxValue) {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621804/saving-state-of-the-checkbox-in-a-custom-list-view-with-checkboxes see this

Comment: if suggesting this coz u r still using the old slow way. use viewholder pattern . also ur if(ischecked) doesnt make sense

Comment: there is missing some in your adapter and if you have more than check boxes then why did you take the sharedPrefarance it will override all the checkbox value with the last provided it. because you taken a single key here.

Comment: gud catch @Concentrated_Attitude

Comment: Thanks @MOSO ,please refer the above link which provide by MOSO because it is a best practice to take a view holder. and if you wanna store more then one check box value then you should create a POJO for that.

Comment: Cheers! Will take a look on that link :)

Comment: cheers @MOSO! Stuff's working properly now :)

Comment: glad it worked..wish upvote comments cud also have earned reputations :p

Answer (score 0):

try Using

```
    editor.commit();
```

instead of

```
    editor.apply();
```

and one more thing that you can pass direct boolean value from onCheckedChanged method like following:

```
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {             
            savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", isChecked);
      }
```